# Direction of vector magnetic potential

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-current, potential

I was reading the [Feynman lecture](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_14.html) about vector magnetic potential and I have a doubt about it. For a certain example it is written that:

> We have, then, a general method for finding the magnetic field of steady currents. The principle is: the $x$-component of vector potential arising from a current density $\boldsymbol{j}$ is the same as the electric potential $\phi$ that would be produced by a charge density $\rho$ equal to $j_x/c^2$—and similarly for the $y$- and $z$-components. (This principle works only with components in fixed directions. The “radial” component of $\boldsymbol{A}$ does not come in the same way from the “radial” component of $\boldsymbol{j}$, for example.) So from the vector current density $\boldsymbol{j}$, we can find $\boldsymbol{A}$ using Eq. (14.19)—that is, we find each component of $\boldsymbol{A}$ by solving three imaginary electrostatic problems for the charge distributions $\rho_1=j_x/c^2$, $\rho_2=j_y/c^2$, and $\rho_3=j_z/c^2$.

So basically it is written that:

- In that specific example each component of the vector magnetic potential is parallel to the corresponding component of current:

  > \begin{equation}
  > \label{Eq:II:14:18}
  > A_x(1)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0  c^2}\int\frac{j_x(2)\,dV_2}{r_{12}},
  > \tag{14-18}\end{equation}
- > this principle works only with components in fixed direction. The radial component of $\boldsymbol{A}$ does not come in the same way from the "radial" component of $\boldsymbol{j}$, for example.

Well, I do not understand this last fact. What does it means "components in fixed direction?". Moreover, which are the reasons behind this statement? What does it determine if $\boldsymbol{A}$ is parallel to $\boldsymbol{J}$ or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Lorenz gauge the Maxwell equations reduce to $$(\partial_t^2 - \nabla )A^\mu = -j^\mu /\epsilon_0 ~.$$ For the time independent case this reduces to Poisson's equations for the scalar and the components of the vector potential. It follows that in the static case the Coulomb law holds for all four components of the potential. It is the concept of gauge invariance that prevents physicists from explaining this up front.

Answer (score 1):

"Components in fixed direction" just means that the coordinate system basis vectors don't vary in space. For example $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ is the same for all $x,y,z$ while $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ depends on the angular coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$.

The magnetic vector potential in the Lorenz gauge is specifically constructed so that we can use the scalar Green function separately for all three Cartesian components. The fact that $\mathbf{A}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{J}$ is really just another way of saying the same thing. It can help you mentally visualize what $\mathbf{A}$ looks like.

Comment: So is Ax parallel to Jx, Ay parallel to Jy and Az parallel to Az, correct? So I'd say that A is parallel to J only if Ax is linked to Jx like Ay to Jy and like Az to Jz. Does this fact depend on the specific medium (for instance if it is isotropic or not)?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo $A_x$, $A_y$, $A_z$, $J_x$, $J_y$, $J_z$ are all scalar quantities, so "parallel" has no meaning here. But you're correct that the three components of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{J}$ must be each "linked" in the same way for $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{J}$ to be parallel.  This indeed requires isotropic materials.

Comment: If you take into account all the currents, including the polarization currents, we are in vacuum, always isotropic? But if you  reason macroscopically, with $\vec{j}$ representing only free currents, the Poisson equation for $\vec{A}$ is no longer verified if the medium is anisotropic.